# Does Statless annotation propagate to extensions of Abstract Class?

Tags: java, ejb, stateless

I've found this **@Stateless** annotation in some code like:

```
public Interface A

@Stateless
public abstract class B implements A

public class C extends B

public class D extends B
```

But Intellij is then saying B shouldn't be declared as *abstract*. Is Intellij right here and the **Stateless** is not actually propagated to the classes extending **B** and I'd have to declare them as **Stateless** or **C**, **D** are properly set as **Stateless**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Stateless in all subclasses too.

Take a look at this: [Inheriting class annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173566/inheriting-class-annotations)

Only the annotations annotated with @Inherited are propagated https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/annotations/inherited-meta-annotation.html